# Using PlotLegends with a numeric PointSize

Tags: plotting, legending

Using `PlotLegends` with a `PlotStyle` containing (for instance) `PointSize[0.02]` creates a legend that does not match the plot.

```
ListPlot[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {20, 2}], {2}],
 PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]
```

[image]

How can I get a sensible legend when using a number with `PointSize`? Solutions involving named sizes (like `PointSize[Medium]`) are inadmissible unless they somehow create points that have a constant size relative to the plot size.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This problem often occurs in plotting and graphics because of the use of `Foo` instead of `AbsoluteFoo` for the directives. The former uses sizes relative to the plot size, whereas the latter, as the name suggests, uses *absolute* sizes.

In the built-in plot legends in version 9, the plot and the legend are actually two separate objects which are just combined, hence `PointSize` uses the figure size of each of those to compute what 0.02 means. All you need to do is to change it to `AbsolutePointSize` to keep it consistent between the two. Of course, the argument will also change and `AbsolutePointSize[7]` looks close enough to what you were gunning for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm disappointed because this kind of trial end error is what I had hoped would be eliminated by the new legends capabilities. I'd say it's not mature yet.

Answer (score 7):

In **version 10** the `PointSize` of the legend will automatically match the `PointSize` of the Plot:

```
ListPlot[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {20, 2}], {2}], 
  PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]
```

[image: MmaVersion10]

---

**Edit:**
The answer by @eldo made me realize, that this is only true up to a `PointSize` that is equal to the default `LegendMarkerSize`. To get bigger matching `PointSize`s:

```
ListPlot[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {20, 2}], {2}], 
 PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[15], 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"a", "b"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 15]]
```

[image: evenBiggerPoints]

For further testing you can use:

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {20, 2}], {2}], 
  PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[ps], 
  PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"a", "b"}, LegendMarkerSize -> ps]],
 {ps, 1, 50}]
```

Comment: Excellent @Karsten ! I was already working on complicated things :)

Comment: @eldo Agree. They improved the `PlotLegends`, but some things still don't work as automated and intuitive as they should and one ends up doing way to complicated stuff.

Comment: BTW, Chapeau for collecting 1.651 pennies within 33 days of membership. Hope your website will pop up soon.

Answer (score 2):

My **V10** output doesn't agree with Karsten's answer, f.e.:

```
ListPlot[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {20, 2}], {2}],
 PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"},
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.05]]
```

[image]

I tried to fix this by building my own `PointLegend`:

```
PointLegend[{
  Directive[Blue, AbsolutePointSize[20]],
  Directive[Orange, AbsolutePointSize[20]]},
 {"a", "b"}]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, above a certain `AbsolutePointSize` the points don't grow anymore but mutate to rectangles.